# Extrair texto de imagem (OCR)

Tags: independente-de-linguagem, ocr

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma biblioteca que consiga fazer a leitura de imagem e extrair o que há nela (pode ser em qualquer linguagem), ou me deem um norte do que devo estudar para entender e desenvolver algo parecido.

**Observação:** Imagem bem simples, com texto em preto e branco.

**Observação2:** Sei que isso deve ser meio complexo, mas estou disposto a correr atrás.

Comment: Você está procurando um OCR? Seria isso? Pergunta vaga...

Comment: Extrair texto? Cores? Objetos? Rostos?

Comment: @TássioAuad isso msm OCR. É q quando fiz a pergunta não sabia por onde começar e lendo as sugestões vi que é OCR

Comment: @PabloAlmeida A inteção é de extrair texto, por exemplo, tiro foto de algum texto em preto e branco e o sistema faz a captura do que está escrito na imagem.

Comment: Defina uma linguagem, OCR pode ser feito em R, JS, C, JAVA, PHP

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio acredito que java ou js sejam interessante pois quero criar um app p android com a função do reconhecimento do conteúdo (texto) de uma foto/imagem. Vc acha viável?

Comment: Sim, a resposta do @Mateus é pertinente, pesquise sobre essa biblioteca Tesseract, existem versões em Java, JS entre outras linguagens também, ai também tem uma biblioteca que faz uso do tesseract: http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe uma biblioteca que já usei em projetos de mobilidade chamada **Tesseract OCR** para reconhecer caracteres em um bitmap. Se trata de uma API que faz reconhecimento de caracteres.

Porém, para calibrar a biblioteca, mais importante que saber utilizá-la, você precisa aprender a "treinar" o Tesseract para que reconheça aquilo que você deseja em uma imagem.